# jQuery/Javascript Functions Don't Work After Changing Content

Tags: jquery, callback

**

### I have solved it by deleting jQuery library imports in the page which I called via ajax.Thanks for your helps guys!

**

I am developing an admin panel for a game.All the things are ok but i have problem with js functions.I have index.php and server.php...I include server.php with ajax callback function.That is OK.I can retrieve all of form content except **head** tags I guess.I have script.js witch has some functions.I add the script both of the pages.When I change content with callback, server.php's functions don't work.

I've read some articles about that.They say change the script.I've changed it the way below you see.It was `$('#dialog_confirm').click` but now that is it.I still can't use functions in server.php. When I open server.php in new tab without callback, it works.What can I do?Thanks in advance.

```
$('#dialog_confirm').live("click", function() {
    $.confirm("confirm?", function() {
        $.msg("yes!");
    }, function() {
        $.msg("canceled");
    });
```

I use [that](http://tinywall.info/2012/02/22/change-browser-url-without-page-reload-refresh-with-ajax-request-using-javascript-html5-history-api-php-jquery-like-facebook-github-navigation-menu/) in order to change page content.

Comment: Are you aware that [`live` is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com)? You should be using `on` (or `delegate` if you're stuck on an older version of jQuery).

Comment: So server.php returns the correct data but where is your ajax code all the code you are showing is related to a dialog button (purely a UI feature and no ajax involved).

Comment: can you give me a little example?I am strange to web languages :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok an example of calling server.php in ajax  then putting the returned data in a tag calls "#putStuff"

```
$.ajax({
  url: "server.php",
  success: function(data) {
     $('#putStuff').html(data);
  } 
});
```

Comment: I think you could just use `.load` then.

Comment: @AbstractChaos, I already call my pages as you wrote.The problem is, js functions don't work at called pages.

Comment: @YağızElesković can you post the code you use to call your page?